# Search function to copy and paste across 2 worksheets needs a number limit on amount of rows pasted

Tags: excel, vba, count, copy-paste, string-matching

As the title says - This code will search Sheet1,Column I for a certain word; e.g "White" and paste all matches into the set row on sheet 2. White represents a martial arts white belt and will paste all student names who are listed as white belt into a set row number/page on sheet2, however i can only fit 30 names on a page and some months there are more than 30 white belts so i need it to paste the first 30 names into the set rows and the remainder in the next page which lets say for example is 5 rows down from the 30th white belt.

There are hundreds of students and 23 different belt levels which always change row numbers on sheet 1 so a fixed method would not work. Please help.

```
Sub ADULTClearAndPaste()

Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT members to cut & past")
Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")

Sh1.Select

lr = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
w = 7
For r = 2 To lr
If Range("I" & r).Value = "White" Then
    Sh2.Cells(w, 5).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, 2).Value
    Sh2.Cells(w, 6).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, 3).Value
    w = w + 1
End If

Next r

py = 79

For r = 2 To lr
If Range("I" & r).Value = "Pro Yellow" Then
    Sh2.Cells(py, 5).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, 2).Value
    Sh2.Cells(py, 6).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, 3).Value
    py = py + 1
End If

Next r
Sh2.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of problems it looks like you will encounter. You are defining w and py as integers but you said that you could have a large number of people in each category and I'm assuming those numbers will change so you could end up with a problem by specifying which row to begin with.

This will allow you to put in your 23 belt colors in as an Array (Changes the Belts(2) to Belts(23) and fill in the colors) and then it will format your second sheet according to how many you have in each color based on the first page.

I am assuming you have a header on the second sheet in the first six rows. You may need to update the Header variable to accurately reference that range, as this will insert a page break then copy that header repeatedly for as long as necessary:

```
Sub ADULTClearAndPaste()
Dim Belts(2) As String
Belts(1) = "White"
Belts(2) = "Pro Yellow"

Dim NewRow As Long
Dim RowCounter As Long
Dim Item As Range
Dim Header As Range
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet

Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT members to cut & past")
Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")
'Specify Header Range
Set Header = Sht2.Range("A1:F6")

NewRow = 7
For i = 1 To UBound(Belts)
    'This creates a new header/page for the next belt color
    If NewRow <> 7 Then
        Sht2.Rows(NewRow).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        Sht2.Range(Sht2.Cells((NewRow), 1), Sht2.Cells((NewRow + 5), 6)).Value = Header.Value
        NewRow = NewRow + 6
    End If

    'This will reference which color is being processed,
    'I put it in there for reference but I figured you would update it
    Sht2.Range("A" & NewRow).Value = Belts(i)
    RowCounter = 0

    For Each Item In Sht1.Range("I1:I" & Sht1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

        If Item.Value = Belts(i) Then
            Sht2.Cells(NewRow, 5).Value = Item.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Sht2.Cells(NewRow, 6).Value = Item.Offset(0, 2).Value
            NewRow = NewRow + 1
            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
            If RowCounter = 30 Then
                'When you hit 30 lines the counter resets and a new header is added
                Sht2.Rows(NewRow).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
                Sht2.Range(Sht2.Cells((NewRow), 1), Sht2.Cells((NewRow + 5), 6)).Value = Header.Value
                NewRow = NewRow + 6
                RowCounter = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next Item
Next i
Sht2.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for this great effort. There are some things that need clarifying I think. in my original code the W and PY are specific places in which i want the names pasted and these values never change. Sh2 needs to stay exactly as it is as there is alot of formatting on it so people can tick which days they come to training. only the names on Sh1 move around and change row number. can you make it do something like find the first white belt on sh1 and count down from there. Thanks again for your help.